# Syntax error when trying to open a file through Python 3 Command Shell

Tags: python

So I am learning Python through Udemy tutorials and now I need to open a file through CMD(CMD is opened on folder I need) and when I am typing function for opening file it says syntax error, but I have made everything good what a guy on tutorials says, I really don't know what what should I do, I checked all of the forums and still cant find the answer.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it seems you are using angle brackets and not parentheses

Comment: Also your file name is  example.txt.txt not example.txt

Comment: Next time you ask a question please add the code and error message as text to the question, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues:

1.Your text file is called "example.txt.txt" instead of "example.txt"

2.The "example.txt","r" should be surrounded with brackets () instead of <>. These symbols look similar in cmd and are easy to confuse.

```
    #instead of
    file = open<"example.txt","r">
    #use
    file = open("example.txt","r")
```

This should fix your problem; let me know if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parenthesss `()` not `<>`

```
file = open("example.txt","r")
```

check https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files